# Compute the shortest path going through three arrays

Tags: javascript

I have three arrays or it may be n. let us take three now.
They have values like these:-

```
Array1=[143, 181];
Array2=[41, 153, 241];
Array3=[22, 67, 131, 190];
```

I want to find those elements of these three array, Who has minimum difference.
Like in this case 143,153,131 has minimum difference.

Comment: What do you exactly minimize ? The sum of the difference ? The difference between the farthest elements ?

Comment: Actually i am trying to solve my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615063/regx-giving-null-with-match-in-jquery, that's why i need this.

Comment: Both three arrays is a positions of elements, So i want difference to get shortest path between them.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please be aware that StackOverflow is here to help you code, not to code for you.

Comment: For this or for previous question?

Comment: @Burki This isn't a trivial question. Computing the shortest path, even without trimming branches, is a little tricky with N arrays, not all developers know how to write this.

Comment: @DenysSéguret i fully agree there. But that does not mean that it should be acceptable that the OP doesn't show his own effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't have a big number of arrays, here's a solution, computing (and storing) all paths:

```
// First let's use a sensible structure
var arrays = [Array1, Array2, Array3];

// Then, let's compute all possible paths
var paths = arrays[0].map(function(v){ return [v] });
for (var i = 1; i<arrays.length; i++) {
   var arr = arrays[i];
   for (var j=paths.length; j--; ) {
      var newPaths = arr.map(function(v){
        return paths[j].concat(v);
      })
      newPaths.unshift(j,1);
      [].splice.apply(paths, newPaths);
   }
}

// Now, let's just take the shortest one
var shortestDistance = Infinity,
    shortestPath = null;
paths.forEach(function(path){
  var distance = 0;
  for (var i=1; i<path.length; i++) {
    distance += Math.abs(path[i]-path[i-1]);
  }
  if (distance<shortestDistance) {
    shortestDistance = distance;
    shortestPath = path;
  }
});

// Finally, let's log the result
console.log(shortestDistance, shortestPath);
```

It logs

```
32
[143, 153, 131]
```

Comment: Thanks. it's awesome. Working correctly. now i will try to solve my previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understood what you want.

You must explore a tree where each array is the list of all descendants of each node, like this:

```
          * (root)
       /      \
   143          181
  / | \        / | \
41 153 241   41 153 241
/|\/|\ /|\   /|\/|\ /|\
........ descendants from 3rd array
```

You can then compute the leaves weights as the difference of the ancestor nodes path to that leaf.

Then you want to find the minimum weight of all leaf nodes.

That's not too difficult if you implement it recursively and keep a variable `minSoFar` and a copy of the nodes to keep the minimum found at any leaf in the tree.

Once this abstract data structure is conceptually clear, the implementation is straightforward and trivial.

EDIT: This implementation has a **small memory footprint** (just the call stack) and should perform on the same order of complexity as the non-recursive version. In both, recursive and non-recursive implementations shown on this page the complexity is dictated by the abstract data structure. Because of the small memory footprint it should be possible to compute pretty deep structures (many arrays) albeit computation time grows exponentially.

```
function recursiveMinDiff(arrays)
{
  var minSoFar, minNodes;

  function computeMinDiff(values)
  {
    var i, vs, total;

    vs = values.slice();
    vs.sort(function (a,b) {      // ascending order
      return a - b;
    });

    total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < vs.length - 1; i++)
    {
      total += vs[i + 1] - vs[i]; // always non-negative
    }

    return total;
  }

  function mindiff(arrays, stack)
  {
    var i, diff, level;

    level = stack.length;
    if (level === arrays.length)  // this is a leaf
    {
      diff = computeMinDiff(stack);
      if (diff < minSoFar)
      {
        minSoFar = diff;          // side-effect on min*
        minNodes = stack.slice(); // clone array
      }
      return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < arrays[level].length; i++)
    {
      stack.push(arrays[level][i]);
      mindiff(arrays, stack);
      stack.pop();
    }
  }

  minSoFar = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  minNodes = [];
  mindiff(arrays, []);

  return minNodes;
}
```

Comment: Ya, That i want, But i got shortestPath from @denys solution and now i get min and max values using math function.

Comment: That's ok, it was more of an exercise to me :) Wrote in PHP first then I realized you required JS. I'll let this here for those who want to understand both implementations.