# JQuery - JSON.stringify not working.

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Guys I am working with a nested menu and I am trying to update via API when the client move some item. I am using this jquery plugin http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/
This plugin has onDrop method:

```
    $(function () {
      var group = $("ol.serialization").sortable({
        group: 'serialization',
        onDrop: function (item, container, _super) {
          var data = group.sortable("serialize").get();

          var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data, null, ' ');
          console.log(jsonString);

          //var jsonString = { name: "John", time: "2pm" };

          $.post( "http://local.api/v1.0/SL-TEST-API-KEY/AbstractBookMenu/", jsonString , function (res) { 
            console.log(res);
          });

          _super(item, container)
        }
      });
    });
```

My api has this code at the moment:

```
Flight::route('POST /v1.0/@key/AbstractBookMenu/', function($key){
    Flight::set('ACCOUNT', Flight::auth()->check(Flight::request(), Flight::get('EVENTLOGIC'), $key));
    $account = Flight::get('ACCOUNT');  

    print_r($_POST);

    die();

});
```

I want to be sure that I received my post data, when I print the res respond in my console **I received an empty array**. However if I try to see the data inside the variable jsonString in the console, I can see that:

```
[
 [
  {
   "id": 22,
   "position": 0,
   "children": [
    [
     {
      "id": 21,
      "position": 0,
      "children": [
       []
      ]
     },
     {
      "id": 24,
      "position": 0
     },
     {
      "id": 29,
      "position": 0
     }
    ]
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": 25,
   "position": 0,
   "children": [
    []
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": 26,
   "position": 0,
   "children": [
    [
     {
      "id": 27,
      "position": 0
     }
    ]
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": 45,
   "position": 30,
   "children": [
    []
   ]
  }
 ]
]
```

For instance, if I try with my commented code

```
var jsonString = { name: "John", time: "2pm" };
```

My API respond is:

```
Array
(
    [name] => John
    [time] => 2pm
)
```

Even, if I try to replace all my json data [[{"id": 21,"position": 0,"children": ... I get this response:

```
Array
(
    [undefined] => 
)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. How can I get this data in my API?. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an object at the outermost level, like this:

```
{
  "mydata": [[{"id" ... // your data goes here
}
```

Comment: yes, the phrasing was confusing. Thank you I've corrected it because it actually is intended as an answer not a *maybe*.

Comment: Yay :D this is nothing, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30620161/3227403) of today took 20 minutes + several edits to get it right :)

Comment: I don't know. And yes, it is unfair. It happens sometimes but there isn't much you can do about it. Keep it up because it makes perfectly sense. Did you solve the problem? If yes, accept an answer or tell us how you solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. You give me the idea I changed my code to get something similar and it is working.